# Problema com CORS em aplicação Angular 7 e WebAPI

Tags: angular

Galera, bom dia.
Estou criando minha primeira aplicação Angular 7 com .NET Core WebAPI.

Após toda estrutura do front montada, fui realizar a comunicação de um get numa api que criei e consegui usando uma extensão para o Chrome que habilita o CORS, de acordo com o método abaixo.

```
getAgenda() {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl)
      .subscribe(d=> console.log(d));
  }
```

** Essa minha variável apiUrl é o meu webapi rodando em localhost.

Com o método acima, consegui obter valores.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando chamo um outro método referente a outro component, usando o POST, eu tenho erro. Observe a tela abaixo:

Método no service:

```
AddTipoPerfil(tipoperfil) {
    this.http.post(apiUrl, tipoperfil)
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

Método do meu component:

```
addTipoPerfil(ret){
    const obj = {
      Nome: ret.value.Nome,
      id: 0
    }

    this.apiService.AddTipoPerfil(obj);
  }
```

** Onde ret é o meu formgroup.

Entidade no meu backend:

```
[Table("TipoPerfil")]
    public class TipoPerfil : Implementation.EntityBase
    {
        [Column("Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Recebo este erro:
[image: Recebo este erro]

Quem puder ajudar, agradeço <3 !

Comment: CORS não é erro é falta de configuração e ou configuração errada, você tem que habilitar no seu backend, quando você faz a requisição para o backend o navegador vai primeiro enviar um pedido para o backend para saber que operações tem disponível, aquele OPTIONS, se a operação não estiver liberada na resposta do OPTIONS o navegador vai bloquear com essa mensagem que você esta vendo. Poste mais informações sobre o seu backend para ser possivel ajudar

Comment: Não fiz nenhuma configuração no meu backend além de configurar o EF Core, talvez seja por isso. Vou pesquisar como configurar, obrigado!

Comment: O endereço da sua api está no localhost certo? experimenta colocar um endereço local para ele. Por exemplo: local-minhaaplicacao.com.br/api e configurar seu front-end com o mesmo dominio: local-minhaaplicacao.com.br.
Já tive esse problema antes, mas como trabalho com outra tecnologia de back-end eu uso NGINX para tal configuração.

Comment: Meu endpoint está sendo http://localhost:5400/api/agenda, no caso, é o endereço do meu api controller. No Angular, há uma url armazenando esse valor e o get é feito nesse endereço.